# How to extract CLOB data from Oracle database in csv or txt?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, clob

I want to extract data from Oracle database in csv or txt format. But because data table fields has CLOB datatype & text in it are more than 256 characters, it exported incomplete using usual extraction method.(Right click & save)

Is there any way to export data from Oracle as it is in csv or txt?

Comment: Define "usual extraction method".  The export utility has no problem handling `CLOB` data.

Comment: @JustinCave: which "export utility" are you referring to? There is no built-in "export" tool in Oracle that can directly create CSV/Text files.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Sorry, I was thinking of SQL*Developer's "save results" function but then brain-farted and wrote about the export utility.

Comment: @JustinCave Right Click & Save. This option available in SQLDeveloper. But did not extract whole data.

Comment: SQL Developer is a pain when CLOBs are involved.